# Java reflection - Where is the method inherited from?

Tags: java, reflection

Can I find out from which class a given method's implementation is inherited? e.g. in the current object, which toString() implementation is used, from Object class, or some other parent class?

Comment: I don't see any option to accept an answer for my old question :(

Comment: Aahh...the option is hard to find for a new visitor!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`Method.getDeclaringClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29) ([link to 1.5 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29))

> `public Class<?> getDeclaringClass()`
>
> Returns the Class object representing the class or interface that declares the method represented by this Method object.
>
> **Specified by:**
>     getDeclaringClass in interface Member
>
> **Returns:**
>      an object representing the declaring class of the underlying member

---

Note that you cannot know if the implementing class only calls the `super`:

```
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}
```

---

To determine the class from which the method is inherited you would need to:

```
class.getMethod("myMethod").getDeclaringClass();
```

---

### Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  System.out.println(String.class.getMethod("toString").getDeclaringClass());
  System.out.println(ArrayList.class.getMethod("toString").getDeclaringClass());
  System.out.println(Area.class.getMethod("toString").getDeclaringClass());
}
```

Outputs:

```
class java.lang.String
class java.util.AbstractCollection
class java.lang.Object
```

---

I noticed from the question that you wanted to get super class that overrides the method if available.  Here is a demo:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ReflectionCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(getInheritedClass(Parent.class.getName(),"overRiddenMethod"));
        System.out.println(getInheritedClass(Child.class.getName(),"overRiddenMethod"));
    }

    public static String getInheritedClass(String className, String method){
        Class clazz;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName(className);

            if(clazz.getSuperclass() != null && clazz.getSuperclass().getMethod(method) != null)
            {
                return clazz.getSuperclass().getName();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return "none";
    }
}

class Parent  {

    public void overRiddenMethod(){

    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    public void overRiddenMethod() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would add the link for Java 7. Java 6 will start EOL in Nov ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Do you like the new styling of the Java 7 api?

Comment: I suppose it looks smarter. The main reason for suggesting Java 7 is that soon it will be the only non EOL version.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: thnx for the notice :) Are there any indications/figures to adoption rate of Java 7? I mean a majority of the clients are probably still running Java 6 on their machines, hence cant make use of the newer stuff, right?

Comment: getDeclaringClass() gives class that that "declared" the method, e.g. for toString() it will always be Object...I want the class from which toString() implementation of my class is inherited from...by default it will be Object class...

Comment: @Sumedh You need to get the method for the class and call getDeclaringClas() on the Method object.

Comment: @posdef I believe the original EOL was June, but as you say, not enough people are ready to move to Java 7.  The EOL period lasts at least a year. After which they only include security and the most critical patches.  It doesn't stop people using old versions. In fact you can download every version/update going back to the first Java 1.1.  The EOL is just the end of free support period (You can pay for it if you can find some one who will give you a price)  which I imagine will get shorter and shorter in future ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks! I think the name of the method should me Method.getDefiningClass() not "declaring" class!